# Redirect image to thumb if it is hotlinked

Tags: image, apache2, resize, hotlinking

A lof of pictures I have on my host are posted full-res on an other forum.

I don't want to spoil the fun completely for the people on the other forum, I'd rather serve a thumbnail. What would be the way to go?

It would only be for the /uploads/ dir. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite and check, whether it's your webpage or other site trying to "view" the image and then use regular expression, check for the image name and add specific thumbnail part of the image.